# UITextField doesn't respond on the google map?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps-sdk-ios, gmsmapview

I'm using google map in my iOS app. I have add GMSMapView and textfield on it but it cannot be touch.Following is my code:

```
 //UI OutletControls
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var mapView: GMSMapView!
@IBOutlet weak var txtF: UITextField!
//UI OutletControls


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //add views
    self.view.addSubview(self.mapView)
    self.mapView.addSubview(self.txtF)

    self.tableView.hidden = true

    /* Setup delegates */
    txtF.delegate = self}
```

Comment: can you show the view hierarchy

Comment: add this `self.mapView.bringSubview(toFront: self.txtF)` and where you checked in simulator or device